# Quebecois: "ta farme tu ta yeule"

Tags: québec, registre-familier

Sur le web j'ai vu cette phrase de temps en temps:

> Ta farme tu ta yeule !

Je crois que ça veut dire en français normal:

> Ferme ta bouche !

Mais évidemment, la première phase n'est pas du français habituel, c'est une tournure de phrase québecoise.  Je ne comprends pas complètement la phrase; quelqu'un peut-il me dire pourquoi cela a la même signification que la traduction en français standard ?

---

I've seen the following phrase on the web from time to time:

> Ta farme tu ta yeule !

I think it means, in standard French:

> Ferme ta bouche ! [shut your mouth!]

But obviously, the former isn't standard French, but a quebecois turn of phrase.  I don't really understand the phrase, so could someone show me how it carries the same meaning as the latter translation into standard French?

Comment: FYI France French is not "normal" French and it is insulting for a Quebecer to read "ca veut dire en français normal". France French uses tons of words that are either not French (profuse amount of English words are used, verlan, etc) or not international French (ie regionalism)

Comment: Relevant: [Should we use the second “tu” in Québec?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1356)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If we exclude the stronger phonetic stuff we get:

> "t'a fermes-tu, ta gueule?"

short for

> "tu (l)a fermes-tu, ta gueule?"

Which amounts to something like "Will you shut it already?!" given that this sounds like it was screamed angrily (and would still be pretty damn rude), I wouldn't feel bad about adding an f-bomb in the English translation either. *Ferme-la!* or *la ferme!* would be the more neutral forms. (I've never seen *bouche* show up in this context.)

As for the phonetics, it is common for /l/ to drop in pronouns if the vowels isn't a schwa. (Cf. /i/ for /il/). This promptly elides into "t'a". /ɛr/ or /ər/ to /ar/ is a very common sound change in informal Quebec French (e.g. *charcher*), while -tu is an emphasizer in questions.

I'm not sure what's the backstory of /yeule/ for *gueule*, but it's a standard lower register pronunciation, and generally palatalisation in front of a front vowel is hardly surprising.

Comment: The general explanation is quite good, I mean for the phonetics, but I'm a bit disappointed by your standard french version. *Tu vas la fermer ta gueule ?* is closer to the quebecois meaning, and still very idiomatic.

Comment: I was looking for a register-neutral version. I have relatively limited version of European informal/slang French.

Comment: No problem, it was just a suggestion for improvement on the standard french slang part. And I'm not myself a quebecois slang expert neither, I just happen to love *Les colocs* and *Loco Locas*, and both tend to make heavy use of that register.

Comment: "Tu la ferme"---> "T'a ferme" in France also, or only Quebec ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this (specifically the elision of *la*'s "L") is mostly a Quebec thing.

Comment: @Circeus Dans certains expressions locales, comme des "sous-patois" (souvent tombés en désuétude, parlé seulement par les anciens) "T'a ferme ti ta gueule", ou "Ti va ti la fermer ta gueule" (suivi [ou pas] d'un "Nom  de Dieu !"

Comment: @cl-r C'est-vrai que le "-ti" de certains dialectes européen a probablement la même source que le -tu québécois. Je crois qu'il se remarque plus en Québécois (du point de vue d'un non-Québécois, s'entend) car il n'est pas ici associé à un groupe régional (ou à peine à un groupe social). Il est parfaitement possible de l'entendre sur les ondes dans la bouche d'un animateur de radio, par exemple (mais peut-être pas à radio-canada, il faut bien le dire XD).

Comment: (1) The deletion of /l/ in _la_ and _les_, object clitic (= pronom atone) or determiner, in the context of a preceding vowel is particular to varieties of Colonial French in North America: _i-a manj a-pòm_ "he eats the apple." A similar rule applies in Haitian Creole for the post-posed determiner adopted from French là "there": _fi-a_ < _fille-là_ "the girl". No such rule applies in Acadian French. (2) The interrogative particle _-tu_ derives from a similar patois particle _ti_ from earlier _-t-il_ (patois = rural dialects of Northern France).

Comment: (3) _yeule, yable, bonjeu, droy_ (for _gueule, diable, bondieu, drogue_) is a case of palatalization common to most European (patois) and American dialects, Acadian included.

Comment: A similar rule applies with the voiceles counterparts /k, t/: _kyen, mokyé_ for _tiens, moitié_.

Comment: (4) The _(l)a_ doubling _yeule_ is obligatory in most varieties of "basilectal" (colloquial) Québécois though ungrammatical in most European varieties. The doubling is a case of "Object Agreement" in terms of syntax.

Answer (score 4):

Being a French Canadian, I think I can help on that.

> T'a fermes-tu ta yeule?

Between this sentence and your "France French" translation, the only real difference is **yeule**. This is deformed word from **gueule**, which means an animal mouth (pejorative for a human).

**T'a** is a shortened *tu la*. This is the same as **Je suis** which often is shortened to **J'suis**, **Chuis** or even **Chu** like in this next sentence :

> Chu ben tanné d'écouter ses jokes plattes.

Fortunately for foreigners, Quebec made a website that explains all of our *[Quebecisms](http://www.immigrer.com/page/outils_dictionnaire-des-expressions-quebecoises.html)*.

Good luck!

Comment: _Tu la fermes ta gueule?_ ou _La fermes-tu ta gueule?_ c'est standard, la répétition _*Tu* la fermes-*tu* ta gueule?_, c'est pour autant que je le sache un québécisme.

Comment: @Unfrancophone, en effet, la répétition vient... marteler le message au destinataire, si je puis dire. Il en augmente le poids. Au Québec, tu n'entendras jamais *Tu la fermes ta gueule?* ni *La fermes-tu ta gueule?*, excepté si la personne imite un Français de France, même si cette phrase est **grammaticalement incorrecte** (la phrase québécoise).

Comment: @Unfrancophone La répétition du son *tu* est une allitération et non la répétition du même mot. Le 1er est le pronom de la 2ePS et le 2e une marque interrogative, connue en France sous la forme *ti*, qui vient de l'ajout d'un *T* euphonique et de la disparition courante du *L* de *il* dans la forme interrogative de certains verbes à la troisième personne (a-t-il, …). Quand *ti* fut ressenti particule interrogative par plusieurs, il convint de spécifier le pronom du verbe: _i va-ti comprendre? —_ Au Québec: _tu vas-tu comprendre?_ / _Vous comprenez-tu?_

Answer (score 1):

"ta farme tu ta yeule" est une contraction de "tu la farme tu ta yeule". En français standard on voit qu'il y a un "tu" de trop et on devrait plutôt écrire "la ferme tu ta gueule".

Plus souvent en québécois on va plutôt dire "farme ta yeule" ou plus simplement "ta yeule" qui en français parisien se dit "ta gueule".

Comment: Il n'a pas un _tu_ "de trop", le _-tu_ après le verbe fléchie correspond à un _esk_ <est-ce que> en français européen. Cf. les commentaires de _Montée de lait_ et de moi-même plus haut.

Answer (score 1):

Yeule : Mot québécois qui fait référence à la bouche. C'est une déformation du mot "gueule", c'est donc un mot assez familier lorsqu'il est utilisé pour un humain.
Par exemple, lorsqu'un québécois te dit de "fermer ta yeule", il te demande de te taire !
La définition complète est ici : http://www.je-parle-quebecois.com/lexique/definition/yeule.html
Toutes les définitions des mots québécois sont ici : http://www.je-parle-quebecois.com/lexique.html