# Utilisation de « tu » dans la phrase « j'ai tu l'air »

Tags: conjugaison, québec, pronoms-personnels

Dans l'œuvre de théâtre [Belles Soeurs](http://blogues.radio-canada.ca/fetes2014/belles-soeurs-un-succes-qui-perdure/) il y a une chanson qui s'appelle "J'ai tu l'air de quelqu'un qui a déjà gagné quelque chose?"

Je comprends grosso modo ce que cette phrase signifie, mais je ne comprends pas très bien les règles de grammaire qui s'appliquent.

Est-ce que "J'ai tu" est l'équivalent de "a-t-il" pour la premier personne du singulier par exemple? Ou peut-être la phrase est un québécisme?

Comment: Il me semble que la question sur [la particule interrogative « -tu »](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois#Particule_interrogative_.C2.AB_-tu_.C2.BB) en français québécois a déjà été posée.

Comment: @Laure Ce lien répond très bien ma question, merci.

Comment: Je ne l'ai pas retrouvé mais je suis sûre qu'on a déjà déjà parlé de ça sur French Stackexchange. Il y a plusieurs Québécois qui rôdent par ici, peut-être retrouveront-ils.

Comment: J'ai trouvé ceci: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11002/quebecois-ta-farme-tu-ta-yeule/11003#11003 mais ce n'est ne pas spécifiquement au sujet de la particule « -tu »

Comment: [This](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/1356).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*J'ai tu* tel qu'énoncé est familier - et utilisé (Québec)

Le sens voulu 'correct' pourrait être exprimé de la manière suivante :

- Ai-je l'air de quelqu'un qui a déjà gagné quelque chose ?
- Est-ce que j'ai l'air de [...]