# Is it possible to have tag questions based on the -tu particle with 'nous' or 'vous' as subject (Quebec)?

Tags: pronoms, oral, questions, québec, interrogative

I've been living in Quebec for a few years now and speak pretty well I think, yet have suddenly been told that when asking questions:

> Vous avez-tu...
> Nous avons-tu...

are wrong, yet all these are ok:

> J'ai-tu...
> T'as-tu...
> On a-tu...
> Y (ils/elles) ont-tu...

As I understood it, the 'tu', is the replacement for 'est-ce que', coming from a bastardisation of something like:

> Est-il -> est-i -> ti -> tu.

It is not the pronoun 'tu'.

So is this just because it sounds gross to a native speaker's ears or is it something I'm not getting? Maybe I'm completely wrong, who knows?

Comment: I doubt it's derived from est-ce que. I would guess that it's derived from the inverted subject, which became grammaticalized into a stand-in for inversion. Really cool effect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should we use the second "tu" in Québec?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1356/should-we-use-the-second-tu-in-qu%c3%a9bec)

Comment: Puis les notes dans cette question https://french.stackexchange.com/q/16078/1893 beaucoup de citations là

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> L'usage de la particule -tu dans une phrase conjuguée avec le « vous
> » n'est généralement pas utilisé, mais on peut parfois rencontrer cet
> usage, habituellement condamné, dans les variétés régionales. [...] Mais l'usage de la particule -tu dans des phrases où le « vous » n'est pas le pronom qui conjugue le verbe est souvent utilisé en français oral et son utilisation est généralement acceptée.
>
> [ Wikipédia, [*Français québécois*](https://L%27usage%20de%20la%20particule%20-tu%20dans%20une%20phrase%20conjugu%C3%A9e%20avec%20le%20%C2%AB%20vous%20%C2%BB%20n%27est%20g%C3%A9n%C3%A9ralement%20pas%20utilis%C3%A9,%20mais%20on%20peut%20parfois%20rencontrer%20cet%20usage,%20habituellement%20condamn%C3%A9,%20dans%20les%20vari%C3%A9t%C3%A9s%20r%C3%A9gionales.) ]

En ce qui me concerne, je suis un locuteur du Québec (Montréal) et je trouve l'emploi du marqueur interrogatif *tu* dans « vous avez-tu... », une phrase conjuguée avec le pronom *vous*, aussi « acceptable » (dans un registre familier) que dans une phrase où ce n'est pas le cas mais qui réfère au pronom *vous* (comme « la poutine est-tu à votre goût ? » ou « ça vous tente-tu vraiment d’y aller ? ») quoique possiblement moins usuel qu'avec les pronoms au singulier. Je trouve « nous avons-tu... » inusité parce que je ne peux imaginer une situation où dans ce contexte j'aurais employé le pronom *nous* plutôt que [*on*](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/21708/la-grammaire/ladjectif/accord-de-ladjectif/accord-de-ladjectif-qui-qualifie-un-pronom-personnel/accord-de-ladjectif-avec-le-pronom-on) (« on a-tu... »).

---

Plus généralement, en ce qui a trait à l'origine :

> La particule « -tu » [t͡sy] est utilisée quand on pose une question
> directe (dont la réponse ne peut être que oui ou non) à quelqu’un. Le
> « -tu » tient alors le rôle d’un adverbe d’interrogation ou
> d’exclamation. Ce « -tu » est dérivé du « -ti », particule
> interrogative du langage populaire en France tirée du « (-)t » de la
> 3<sup>e</sup> personne verbale accolé au pronom « il » comme dans « Y en a-t-il
> d’autres? » ou « Faut-il être fou? », perdant graduellement le « l »
> comme dans « C’est-y pas possible? » et se mettant dans des phrases
> qui ne nécessitent pas de pronom indirect « il y a ». Par conséquent,
> cette particule « -tu » (considérée comme particule à part entière et
> non comme pronom personnel dans ce contexte) transforme en
> interrogation ou exclamation une phrase qui sans elle serait
> simplement une affirmation.
>
> [ Wikipédia, [*Français québécois*](https://L%27usage%20de%20la%20particule%20-tu%20dans%20une%20phrase%20conjugu%C3%A9e%20avec%20le%20%C2%AB%20vous%20%C2%BB%20n%27est%20g%C3%A9n%C3%A9ralement%20pas%20utilis%C3%A9,%20mais%20on%20peut%20parfois%20rencontrer%20cet%20usage,%20habituellement%20condamn%C3%A9,%20dans%20les%20vari%C3%A9t%C3%A9s%20r%C3%A9gionales.), notes omises, mais on lira avec intérêt la [note 56](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois#cite_note-56), [ce lien](http://www.nou-la.org/ling/1995a-fda.pdf) ]

Bien des prototypes de phrases interrogatives contiennent la syllabe *t-il(s)* et on a une prononciation populaire de cette particule où on a amuïssement et qui varie et on obtient ce -tu dont on parle. Voir aussi au *Wiktionnaire* les particules « [tu](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tu#Particule) », « [ti](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ti#fr-part) », « [y](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/y#fr-part) », et la forme « [t-il](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/t-il) » et le LBU14 § 395 en partie résumé [ailleurs](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/16078) et contenant des exemples comme : « Vous avez-T-IL déjà vu l'Diable ? » (Maupassant), « Vous êtes-T-Y prêts ? » (Dorgelès).

Comment: La réponse a été sélectionnée (merci) mais n'est pas particulièrement bien rédigée et une réponse en anglais ou de quelqu'un qui possède davantage le sujet serait sans doute utile.